# How do I evaluate $\prod_{r=1}^{\infty }\left (1-\frac{1}{\sqrt {r+1}}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, infinite-product

I am not being able to find the specific product $\prod_{r=1}^{k} \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt {r+1}}\right)$ so to evaluate the given problem when $k \to \infty $.

Comment: Presumably it "diverges to 0".

Comment: @almagest Yes you are right. But how?

Comment: Why not use the usual approach? Each term is less than $e^{-1/\sqrt{r+1}}$ and the corresponding series diverges.

Comment: @StubbornAtom One at least knows that the product is less than $1$, for every term is less than $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The product is $0$ (therefore by the definition of a converging infinite product your product does not really converge). For every integer $n\geq 1$ we have
\begin{equation*}
0 \,<\, \prod_{r=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{r+1}}\right)
\,\leq\, \exp\left(-\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{r+1}}\right)~.
\end{equation*}
The series $\sum_{r=1}^\infty 1/\sqrt{r+1}$ diverges, so the partial products of your infinite product tend to $0$.

Answer (score 4):

If you know that, for $0<a_n<1$, we have
$$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-a_n) = 0 \text{ if and only if } \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n = \infty$$
then it suffices if you show that 
$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{r+1}} = +\infty.$$

For the proof of the above general fact, see
[How to prove $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-a_n) = 0$ iff $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n = \infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519656/how-to-prove-prod-i-1-infty-1-a-n-0-iff-sum-i-1-infty-a-n)

For the series which you get see, for example, [Is $\sum\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ convergent or divergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034490/is-sum-frac1-sqrtn1-convergent-or-divergent)